# WIndows 10 Core IOT Project Types other than UAP

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

I am working with a RaspberryPi and Windows 10 IOT.  I've run through the Hello World samples and am ready to try some more in-depth robot programming.  I use Akka.Net a lot in this but can't get it to load via Nuget in the UAP.  I get a cannot install error because it says that Akka.Net doesn't contain assembly references for Windows Verison 8.1.  Can I deploy console apps or services to windows IOT?  Or am I stuck waiting until Akka.Net adds a Windows 8.1 build target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stuck (for now).  Remember that you're basically targeting the equivalent of Windows Phone.  There are a ton of libraries that aren't available in the specific .Net Framework on the device, including System.Net (which kills a lot, including Akka.net)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 IoT Core only supports UWP, you can't use API and libraries that are not written for UWP. Someone have to rewrite them for UWP.

> **Just, for the reference (due to question title):**
>   Latest version of Windows 10 IoT Core (Build 10586) supports multiple project templates. You can find complete list of templates at: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/55b357e1-a533-43ad-82a5-a88ac4b01dec
>
> Arduino Wiring project template is now supported into Windows 10 IoT Core. Refer following project article to understand Arduino Wiring for Windows 10 IoT Core: https://www.hackster.io/AnuragVasanwala/windows-10-iot-core-hydroflyer-f83190

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a fairly old post, but a quick update to this question is
Windows IoT does support console application, but it's limited to C++ programming.

Follow a nice tutorial from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/memorystatus) to find out how.